# Count how many cells exceed other cells' value

Tags: excel, vba

(I'm a straight up beginner, first month of assignments of vba)

In my assignment, I was given an excel file with 4 sheets (of which, for my question, only the first three matter). Each of those first three's names end with the date (MM/YY) (0920, 1020 and 1120 respectively). In all those sheets I have two columns - one with a minimum value, and the other with the real value.

I need to create a procedure that, with a certain input of month and year, goes to the respective sheet and calculates how many cells with the real value have a value larger than their respective minimum value.

I tried this:

```
Sub ArtigosArmazem()
    folhas = Array("Stock final 0920", "Stock final 1020", "Stock final 1120")
        For i = LBound(folhas) To UBound(folhas)
            Worksheets(folhas(i)).Activate
        Next
    Dim n As Integer
    x = InputBox("Ano")
    y = InputBox("Mês")
    n = 0
    If x = 2020 And y = setembro Then
        i = "Stock final 0920"
        For k = 3 To 510
            If Cells(k, 8) > Cells(k, 7) Then
            n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox(n)
    End If
End Sub
```

("Ano" means year, "Mês" means month and "setembro" means september in portuguese)

But it kept outputting "0" in the Message Box. Any help or tips?

Comment: What’s the problem with the code you have? Also pls [edit] your question and add some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue, then I think you need something like this using VBA.

```
Sub ArtigosArmazem()

Dim x  as Integer
Dim y as String 
Dim n as Integer
dim k as Integer

  x = InputBox("Ano")
  y = InputBox("Mês")
  n = 0
  If x = 2020 And y = "setembro" Then
      Sheets("Stock final 0920").Activate
      For k = 3 To 510
          If Cells(k, 8) > Cells(k, 7) Then
          n = n + 1
          End If
      Next
      MsgBox(n)
  End If
End Sub
```

With this method you have to watch out for the capitalization of "setembro".  In VBA unlike Excel, "setembro" <> "Setembro".

It might be easier to use `=SUMPRODUCT((H3:H510>G3:G510)*1)` in each sheet instead of VBA.

This works in my version of Excel O365.  I believe it will work in earlier versions as well.